# Is MXGP the most important circuit for motocross?

Tags: international-sports, road-racing

Is [MXGP](http://www.mxgp.com/) the most important circuit for motocross in the world?

I do not know any other races in this typology

Comment: Define "most important."

Comment: I ask another [question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13887/what-are-the-motocross-championship-with-worldwide-echo) that can help

Comment: @Ale i didn't get this question.